# Appium android driver

Tags: android, appium

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

import android.provider.Browser;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

import com.example.secretsanta.MainActivity;

public class AppiumExampleTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    private RemoteWebDriver driver;

    public AppiumExampleTest(Class <MainActivity> activityClass) {
        super(activityClass);
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() throws MalformedURLException {
        File appDir = new File("../secret_santa//bin");
        File app = new File(appDir, "secret_santa.apk");

        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("version", "5");
        caps.setCapability("device", "emulator-5554");
        caps.setCapability("platform", "ANDROID");
        caps.setCapability("browser", "CHROME");
        caps.setCapability("app-package", "com.example.secretsanta");
        caps.setCapability("app-activity", "MainActivity.class");
        caps.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());


            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);


        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

    @Test
    public void testAppiumExample() throws Exception {

        // find button with label or content-description "Button 1"

        driver.findElement(By.id("createListButton")).click();

        // click on button and start second Activity

        // we are on second screen now
        // check if second screen contains element with text “Activity2”
        driver.findElement(By.id("createListView"));

        // click back button
        HashMap<String, Integer> keycode = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        keycode.put("keycode", 4);
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("mobile: keyevent", keycode);
        //
        // // we are again in main activity
        driver.findElement(By.id("createListButton"));
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

}
```

I am trying to press the button and then go to the next activity and then return to the main activity. At the moment I have a few errors, one with the actvityinstrumentationtestcase2 and then the constructor and then another with the element.

Comment: ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 test classes are loaded by the InstrumentationRunner and run on a Dalvik VM on the device. Appium classes on the other hand are loaded on a JVM on the host itself and talk to the Appium server which in turn talks to the device. Are you sure it is the right thing to define Appium code inside ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use

`private RemoteWebDriver driver;`

instead of

`private WebDriver driver;` ?

Like that it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Appium driver instead:

```
protected AppiumDriver driver;
```

Comment: I have tried this and AppiumDriver cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: make sure you have all the jar files. junit 4.11 and java client. If you already have it, try to remove it and add it again.

Answer (score 0):

And you also can try to have in your Test Base (parent) class the following:

```
    public static AppiumDriver getDriver() {
    return driver;
}
```

Comment: I may not be using this in the correct way but this also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

`driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);`

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set capabilities something like the following:

```
  public class AbstractTest{

    public static AndroidDriver driver;
    private static String appFileName = "";
    private static String appDirName = "";
    public static String appPack = "";

    static File app;
    static File appDir;

    static DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

    @BeforeSuite
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {

        try {
            appFileName = PropertyLoader.loadProperty("appFileName");
            appDirName = PropertyLoader.loadProperty("appDirName");
            appPack = PropertyLoader.loadProperty("appPack");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        appDir = new File(appDirName);
        app = new File(appDir, appFileName);

        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "Appium");

        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,
                MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
//      For Android Emulator
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
        cap.setCapability("app","C:\\secret\\secret\\secret\\secret.apk");

        cap.setCapability("appPackage","secret");

        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
        cap.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", "True");


        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver),new LoginPage());


    }
```

you should provide your actual file name, dir name, pack name and so on

Comment: PropertyLoader is just example, don't use it, "hard code" your actual properties

Comment: `import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobilePlatform;`

Comment: I now have errors on the import for the AndroidDriver, what else is needed to be able to use the AndroidDriver?

Comment: is it you first Android project? Have you got Android SDK installed and so on? Have you got corresponding dependencies in your pom.xml?

Comment: No pom file and I have got Android SDK installed